# Submit Form and Open in prettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, forms

I have a form that submits values to a cold fusion page, and I'd like that page to launch in a prettyPhoto lightbox. Here's the basic code for the form:

```
<form name="CFForm_1" action="../water/search_results2.cfm" method="post" onsubmit="return _CF_checkCFForm_1(this)" rel="prettyPhoto" >
```

And here's the submit:

```
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value=" Submit Query " >
```

Here is the example page:
http://dev.fosr.org/water-query/?sid=NS46

Running Wordpress and PrettyPhoto Media plugin, any guesses on how to accomplish this? I've done a good bit of research, but everything I've found deals with opening / validating a form with prettyPhoto.

In my case, I want the form to SUBMIT / OPEN the results in a lightbox

Comment: Michael, I'm in exactly the same position as you were. Could you provide a complete example of how this problem was finally solved. The solution didn't submit the form for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Abschicken" id="submit" name="submit" rel="prettyPhoto" onclick="$.prettyPhoto.open('mailer.php?ajax=true&width=60%&height=20%'); return false;" />
```

Comment: That didn't submit the form for me. Could you show how you've coded the form attributes, i.e. method=post etc